# Adding Toggle Class to this jQuery...?

Tags: jquery, toggle

Can someone help me out with this please?

A simple toggle to hide and show areas works perfectly, i need to add a class to the p tag of the one that is open and remove it when its closed.

Currently this only adds it but it stays added and doesn't remove it, even when you click to close. :(

```
$(".parents-toggle > p").click(function () {
$(this).toggleClass('open');
   $(".parents-toggle > div.menu-toggle").not($(this).siblings()).slideUp();
   $(this).siblings(".menu-toggle").slideToggle();

});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Thans jon :)

<div class="parents-toggle">
<p><a>button 1</a></p>
<div class="menu-toggle hidden-toggle">
<div class="menu-toggle-one">
 box content 
 </div><!--menu-toggle-one-->
</div> <!--menu-toggle-->
 </div>  <!--parents-toggle-->

<div class="parents-toggle">
<p><a>button 2</a></p>
<div class="menu-toggle hidden-toggle">
<div class="menu-toggle-one">
 box content 
 </div><!--menu-toggle-one-->
</div> <!--menu-toggle-->
 </div>  <!--parents-toggle-->

Comment: Sorry here is better.. http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/UXE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the DOM inspector on jsFiddle it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Gv8Y2/

**EDIT:**

Try

```
$(".parents-toggle > p").click(function () {
    $( ".parents-toggle > p").not(this).removeClass("open");
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $(".parents-toggle > div.menu-toggle").not($(this).siblings()).slideUp();
    $(this).siblings(".menu-toggle").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: The Toggle drop down works fine and indeedif just click the same button on then off the class is added and removed fine.

However, if you click one button then another different separate button the class remains on the original button and never removed unless you refresh.